# How to setup server run Node.js?

Tags: node.js, linux, socket.io, centos7, vps

I have a VPS to run Server for my game. I use `node.js` and `socket.io`. I found some tutorial config my `my-app-name.service` file like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /usr/games/nodeapp/app.js
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=my-app-name
User=hnp
Group=hnp
Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=5000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But, when I connect to server from **mydomain.com** by socket.io:

```
io('http://<my_server_ip>:5000')
```

I got error:

```
GET http://<my_server_ip>/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LfqMeQU net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

My `app.js`

```
var http = require('http');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var ip = process.env.IP || 'localhost';
server = http.createServer().listen(port, ip, function() {
   console.log('Server running at %s:%s!', ip, port);
});
var io = socketIO.listen(server);
io.set('match origin protocol', true);
io.set('origins', '*:*');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've been doing it. I use [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/), though:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(app);

io = require("socket.io")(server);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 80, "YOUR_IP");
```

Client:

```
var socket = io();
```

Comment: Client in another domain and diff server. My VPS just run Node.js app, and my website will connect to it.

Comment: @OmegaP could you try changing the port to `80`? I can simulate the same problem with port `5000`, but if I change it to `80`, it works.

Comment: @OmegaP I have a project using the Heroku services. It also uses port 5000 and there, I have `server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);` on the server and `socket = io();` on the client. I don't specify the IP there. You could try the same?

Comment: I access to server from another server. Just like, connect to `app-name.heroku.com:port` from `mydomain.com` and don't use `express`